# Error in accessing derived class function from base class pointer

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am unable to access derived class function from base class pointer.
Her is my code

```
#include<iostream>

class base
{
public:
void fun()
{
cout<<"Base class";
}
};

class der:public base
{
public:
    void fun()
    {
     cout<<"Derived class";
    }
};

int main()
{
 clrscr();
 base* pb;

 //der d1;
 //pb=&d1;             uncommenting these lines and commenting the below line 
 //pb->fun();          also gives an error

 static_cast<der*>(pb)->fun();      //error here ((der*)pb)->fun() works fine


 return 0;
}
```

What i know is if u have many derived classes derived from base classes & suppose u don't have to create that many derived class objects then u create a base class pointer.
Accessing derived class functions from base class pointer is a topic of interest here.I also heard that **base class pointer** is a **generic pointer** so it can hold address of a derived class object.So why can't we directly do this

```
der d1;
pb=&d1;  
pb->fun();
```

Derived class fun() should be called.

But it gives a compile time error. Why?

Comment: `der` does not derive from `base` in your code. you need `class der : public base` syntax in place of `class der`

Comment: class der:public base

Comment: that doesn't work still

Comment: [it does, click this link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4c12d1993d2c8d5), but maybe you meant to make the `fun` member function `virtual` ?

Comment: no i don't want to make it virtual...

Comment: so what *"does not work still"* ? any error you see that I don't ?

Comment: i think my turbo c++ compiler has gone drunk

Comment: if you have some error, why don't you share it?

Comment: You must make it virtual if you want the polymorphic behavior you describe in your last example.  That's what `virtual` means.

Comment: directly did base* pb;static_cast<der*>(pb)->fun(); shows an error

Comment: without `virtual` you can not achieve that you are trying to do.

Comment: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php  works fine      my compiler had gone drunk

Comment: its an example of down casting

Answer (score 0):

make your base class `fun()` function `virtual`

try this:

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>

class base
{
public:
   virtual void fun()
   {
    cout<<"Base class";
   }
};

class der :public base
{
public:
     void fun()
    {
     cout<<"Derived class";
    }
};

int main()
{

 base* pb=new der();

 pb->fun();         

 return 0;
}
```